# Insert blank rows at specific intervals

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to insert a set number of rows every row. I.e. spread my condensed data out.

The code below worked with variables as int's but since changing to long due to dataset size it has seemed to have broken. It just pushes all the rows from row 2 down a few thousand as a single group. The goal is to have 74 lines in between my existing data set

```
Sub Run()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim xInterval As Integer
Dim xRows As Integer
Dim xRowsCount As Long
Dim xNum1 As Long
Dim xNum2 As Long
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xLast As Long


xTitleId = "Input"

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

xRowsCount = WorkRng.Rows.count

xInterval = Application.InputBox("Enter row interval. ", xTitleId, 1, Type:=1)

xRows = Application.InputBox("How many rows to insert at each interval? ", xTitleId, 1, Type:=1)

xNum1 = WorkRng.Row + xInterval

Set xWs = WorkRng.Parent

For i = 1 To Int(xRowsCount / xInterval)
    xWs.Range(xWs.Cells(xNum1, WorkRng.Column), xWs.Cells(xNum1 + xRows - 1, WorkRng.Column)).Select
    Application.Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    xNum1 = xNum1 + xNum2
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: To start with, I think you will have to loop backwards.

Comment: ```xnum1``` will never change because ```xnum2``` has no value

Comment: Hey @SJR could you explain how the loop is backwards, it does seem to work as its intended 
By changing to xNum to long and the loop to be cLng it fixed the problem

Comment: Also, thanks @Warcupine for that pick up, no need to include it unless the interval needs to get bigger each time :)

Comment: If you loop from 1 to 10 and are inserting rows your last row will have moved beyond 10 but your loop will stop there, leaving the rest of your data unaffected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not do it like this?

```
Sub Run()

Dim xInterval As Long
Dim xRows As Long, i As Long
Dim xRowsCount As Long
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xTitleId As String

xTitleId = "Input"

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

xRowsCount = WorkRng.Rows.Count                                                                     '100
xInterval = Application.InputBox("Enter row interval. ", xTitleId, 1, Type:=1)                      '5
xRows = Application.InputBox("How many rows to insert at each interval? ", xTitleId, 1, Type:=1)    '3

Set xWs = WorkRng.Parent

For i = xRowsCount To 1 Step (-1 * xInterval)
    xWs.Cells(i, 1).Resize(xRows).EntireRow.Insert
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @SJR this did the trick but also changing original code to xNum as Long and cLng in the loop fixed it

Comment: Glad it worked. Yes, always use `Long` rather than `Integer`.